# Custom URL for Component Search Results

Tags: joomla, seo, content-management-system, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am writing to seek help to display custom results in a SEF URL on Joomla CMS.

Example: This is a page with a customized search, https://jobwalkins.in/search.html?search=IT&exf_5=1&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147

I would like to display this link as https://jobwalkins.in/today-walkins-in-hyderabad.html

I am using https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jom-classifieds/ as the extensions.

Any helpful inputs will be greatly appreciated. I am looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Best Regards, 
Syed H

Comment: Have you enabled System - "SEF plugin" in Joomla/administrator/extensions/plugins ?

Comment: Also, you should check the docs of this component more. At the top right you can choose and read about "SEO settings" of the configurations: https://jomclassifieds.com/site-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I have already tried that but had no luck. I also tried CMShortURL https://cmext.vn/products/cmshorturl however, I had no luck achieving it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: classifieds is a complex third party joomla component. However I know how to generate SEF urls programmatically in Joomla, but the best would be if you just send an email to the component developers and ask them about exact settings to achieve your goals regarding the generated links. I’m sure they can help you with that quite fast.

Comment: I already had a word with developers. They are quite busy and could not help me at this time. They are usually very responsive and helpful. But this time, they are too engaged.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired output using https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef/. The website in question https://jobwalkins.in/ now shows the predefined search results in custom URLs.

Here are a few of them which I was able to achieve:

https://jobwalkins.in/jobs-in-bangalore.html where the actual link was https://jobwalkins.in/search.html?search=&exf_5=2&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147
https://jobwalkins.in/today-walkins-in-hyderabad.html where the actual link was https://jobwalkins.in/search.html?search=&exf_5=1&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147

It works even for the links where the keywords are searched ex:

I searched for a keyword "fresher" and have set the page to render on custom URL https://jobwalkins.in/fresher-jobs.html where the actual link was https://jobwalkins.in/search.html?search=fresher&exf_5=-1&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147

The sh404SEF https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef/ worked great and helped me address my concern very well.

Hope this post is useful for someone who may have a similar issue.